# Jest and Typescript - Mocking a const in a function

Tags: typescript, jestjs

New to Jest here and not sure how I would do this:

Say I have some function that contains a `const` that I've set to a specific type (`newArtist`):

```
export class myTestClass {
    async map(document: string) {
        const artist: newArtist = document.metadata.artist;
        ...
        }
}
```

And along with that I have:

```
export interface newArtist {
    name: string;
    title: string;
}
```

Now when I write a test, if I do say something like:

```
it("My example test", async () => {
    const result: any = await new myTestClass(__context()).map({
        name: "An Artist"
        title: null
    });
        ...
}
```

The test will fail because `title` is set to null. I need that interface to be a little different for the purposes of the test - basically to be be something like:

```
export interface newArtist {
    name: string;
    title: string | null;
}
```

How can I do that? I've seen mocking classes, but wouldn't that mean I end up copying/pasting all the `map` function code?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure the reason is about `null` and typecheck? To me you passes data with irrelevant structure: instead of `string` that has property `metadata` of type `object` you pass this `object` directly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear what do you try to do. The code you provide is incorrect.

For me, the below code works fine with typescript and jest. Please give more information.

`index.ts`:

```js
export interface INewArtist {
  name: string;
  title: string | null;
}

export interface IDocument {
  metadata: {
    artist: INewArtist;
  };
}

export class MyTestClass {
  constructor(private readonly ctx) {}
  public async map(document: IDocument) {
    const artist: INewArtist = document.metadata.artist;
  }
}
```

Unit test:

```js
import { MyTestClass, IDocument } from './';

// tslint:disable-next-line: variable-name
const __context = () => {};

describe('MyTestClass', () => {
  it('My example test', async () => {
    const document: IDocument = {
      metadata: {
        artist: {
          name: 'An Artist',
          title: null
        }
      }
    };

    const result: any = await new MyTestClass(__context()).map(document);
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/56847385/index.spec.ts
  MyTestClass
    ✓ My example test (3ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.396s
```